# How can I resolve the stringFormat Exception error?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

[image]

```
 var date=  DateTime.ParseExact("16-03-2022 1:30", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When I enter `16-03-2022 13:30`, it does not give an error but when the parameter is `16-03-2022 1:30`, I get an error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Change `HH` to `H`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code (and value, and error message) as *text*. Keep the image if you think that's useful, but fundamentally this is textual information.

Comment: please paste your code as text and not as an unreadable tiny picture. Maybe it has something to do with CulturInfo?

Comment: Ultimately, 1:30 is not HH:mm - that would be 01:30 or 13:30 (am vs pm). Decide whether the format or the data is wrong, and fix that!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like taking a risk to answer but..

Let's go step by step. One of the good things about .NET methods is that you can see what exceptions can be thrown on that method in their documentation.

From "Exception" section on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string-system-iformatprovider)) it says;

> `FormatException`
>
> `s` or `format` is an empty string.
>
> -or-
>
> `s` does not contain a date and time that corresponds to the pattern
> specified in `format`.
>
> -or-
>
> The hour component and the AM/PM designator in `s` do not agree.

Your `s` or `format` is not empty, your string does not have any AM or PM designator, so the only option left is "`s` does not contain a date and time that corresponds to the pattern specified in `format`." as a reason.

Also from documentation, it says;

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
> DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
> format information. **The format of the string representation must match
> the specified format exactly.**

What "format" we are talking about? There are two of them. [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and [Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings). Since we are using `DateTime.ParseExact`, we need to consider using custom date and time format.

Let's look at all parts can be parse in your `16-03-2022 1:30` string;

- 16 --> Two digit day number (`dd`)
- 03 --> Two digit month number with leading zero (`MM`)
- 2022 --> Four digit year (`yyyy`)
- 1 --> One digit hour (it can be `h` or `H` because there is no time designator in your string and we *can't* know it's in [12-hour clock format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) or [24-hour clock format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock))
- 30 --> Two digit minutes (`mm`)

So, the proper format of your `16-03-2022 1:30` string can be either `dd-MM-yyyy H:mm` or `dd-MM-yyyy h:mm` which depends on **you**. If it is 24-hour format, use `H` specifier, if it is 12-hour format, use `h` specifier.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the word "**Exact**" in `ParseExact()`, it means it. Any deviation from the expected format at all will cause an exception.

In this case, the `HH` specifier is not an exact match for the `1` value for the hour. It would match if you had `01` instead, but just `1` isn't the same thing. To match the hours without leading zeros you need a single `H`, creating this format string:

```
dd-MM-yyyy H:mm
```

This will still match later hours like "10" and "11". Additionally, the capital "H" instead of lower-case means it still expects 24-hour time, so numbers like "13" up to "23" still work, too.

If you could get a mix of values, that sometimes has just the `1` and sometimes might have the full `01`, then you need to use a [ParseExact() overload that accepts an array of formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles)), and provide both versions.